# Is it impossible to be a certain rank, say, Gold 3, without having won or drawn against an opposing team where at least 1 player was at least Gold 2?

Tags: achievements, counter-strike-global-offensive, valorant

**Note 1**: I think this question is the same for **csgo or valorant**, but if you want I can double ask this question, 1 for each game. It'll have the same answers anyway I believe. Up to you. To avoid such closure you may assume this is csgo. (And treat 'Gold 3' as 'Gold Nova 3'.)

---

**Question**:

Is it impossible (except I guess when the game was 1st released) to be Gold 3 without having won or drawn against an opposing team where at least 1 player was (at the time) peak-ranked at least Gold 2?

**More generally**:

If someone, call this person Alice, has a certain rank X at time T then, among all the opponents in all the games Alice has played up to time T (excluding possible ongoing games), where the result was win or draw for Alice, at least 1 person should have at least peak-rank X-1 (as of the start of the game) right?

- I mean I think Alice can't be, say, Gold 3 on 2022Jan01 12am and then ALL Alice's opponents in ALL Alice's games up to 2021Dec31 11:59pm (excluding a possible ongoing game that passes through 2021Dec31 11:59pm - 2021Jan01 12am), where the result was win or draw for Alice, were ALL Gold 1 or lower.

---

**Note 2**: If it makes a difference, then you may answer

1. for the cases of **then peak-ranked** Gold 2 or higher (but may be ranked lower at the time) vs of **then-ranked** Gold 2 or higher (but may have been ranked higher before)
2. for the cases of all players that Alice's team **won or drew** against were Gold 1 or lower vs of all players that Alice's team **played against (including possibly lost against)** were Gold 1 or lower

Looks like 4 possible cases total (8 if you do the 4 cases for each of the 2 games), but I don't think it really matters.

---

**Related/Context**:

1. [Farming: Prevent reaching a certain rating without having beaten/drawn someone of that rating (up to a point of course)?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41449/farming-prevent-reaching-a-certain-rating-without-having-beaten-drawn-someone-o)
2. [Farming: Is it unethical to gain rating by playing against only weaker players?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41450/farming-is-it-unethical-to-gain-rating-by-playing-against-only-weaker-players)

Comment: I feel like this is unlikely to be the same for CS:GO and Valorant, since it's unlikely that the two games use the exact same (proprietary) ranking system.

Comment: @Schism thanks, but i don't think they need to be exactly the same. if you're MG1 or Platinum 1, then surely you must have beaten or drawn with someone who is at least Gold 3 right? What about Gold 2? Gold 1?

Comment: The *displayed* skill group in CS:GO does not necessarily reflect the *non-public* MMR in use for a player. Its just a rough indicator, and may lag behind the actual number - and is even routinely hidden after major adjustments, requesting a certain number of wins before one can see it again.

Comment: @chebureki interesting. thanks for sharing. so a non-public MMR could be like 1300 but the displayed skill group is s6 instead of the appropriate GN1 because of example making additional requirements like say more wins or more wins against higher ranked players? this would really prove my point about 9LX ratings...

Comment: I don't think CS allows for any insights into chess matters. Of course Valve can allow for trade-offs and quirks. Because while people seem to want the chess rating to express skill at various levels, nobody cares about your public rank, whether its in the Valve ladder or elsewhere. They are just tools for low-effort training matches. Think you are good? Bring your team to tournaments! Qualification does not take sufficient games for ELO peculiarities to even matter.

Comment: @chebureki 'I don't think CS allows for any insights into chess matters.' --> it's ok.  let the community be the judge of that. thanks anyway. this post is about cs/csgo/valorant. (btw my goal is 9LX not chess. lol. it's not just a nitpick btw. there's a particular issue in matchmaking in 9LX that chess doesn't have but it's supposed to be so easy to fix.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance, but its incredibly low.

I dont know exactly how matchmaking is done in CSGO but there is always a range of ranks in the same game. Usually within 2 major ranks (in valorant, if you are gold you will match sometimes with silvers, sometimes with golds, sometimes against diamonds. More often than not there will be more than one major rank represented in the game.) You could see that by using things like OP.GG

The range could be higher or lower depending on how much people are playing. The game basically does a balance of giving you something as close as possible to you (a balanced match) and you not having to wait 4 hours for the PERFECT match. So you always have a range of ranks in your games. Above and below you.

Is it possible? By luck, its very improbable. It would be lottery style odds to never have to hit someone higher than where you end up in match making. It would basically need an act of god to never see a Gold 2+ person and end up gold 3. Something like every single player seemingly quits when hitting Gold 2.

Comment: ok fine thanks Fredy31♦. but surely this drops to next to impossible if the requirements further separate like whatever is after gold vs gold 1 max or after gold vs whatever is before gold max right?

Comment: Matchmaking has quirks for every game. But as far as I know you will always match around your rating (or the average rating of the party you queue with) and there is usually no cutoff of 'people under the cutoff cannot play people above the cutoff'

Comment: Fredy31♦ interesting. so, what, it's possible to reach say MG1 or Platinum 1 without ever beating or drawing against a Gold 1 or higher? (again, you can answer for any of the 8 cases [or just 4 cases if you're talking valorant] but please specify if it makes a difference. so depending on the case you choose, you might have played against gold 1 or higher but have never beaten or drawn with them)

Comment: btw re "there is usually no cutoff of 'people under the cutoff cannot play people above the cutoff'" i'm not talking about future matchmaking. i'm talking about past matchmaking. like given your current rank is this, what can we say about the rank of your opponents that you have won/drawn/lost again? specifically i'm asking **to be a Gold 3, do you pretty much have to have beaten/drawn with another Gold 3 or higher**? if no, then what about Gold 2? Gold 1? how low can this go?

Comment: What I was getting at is that if there was a system that would prevent you from playing against someone above your level, or above x level (like you can't play with someone one major rank above you) you would see it if you tried to queue with someone above that limit. And on millions and millions of players you know someone, somewhere, would have tried to queue with someone above the cutoff and for some reason, cant.

Comment: And for the detailed response to the question you are asking, yes and no, ELO is a very big subject to get into. To heavily simplify things, the ELO gained or lost after a game depends on your opponents. If the difference is big in their favor but you win, you will get a lot of ELO. If you win against a team that is ranked lower than you on average, you will win less. I dont know if the system would break down if you never met someone higher than the ELO you say, but I think you, in any condition, would still win a little bit of ELO every time and thus, gaining the rank.

Comment: As far as I know, most games run a modified system based on Chess ELO System https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system There is LOTS of maths involved.

Comment: thanks, but i don't think you answered my questions directly. i am very well aware of elo (it's not ELO actually) glicko etc in chess or 9LX. I actually ask here [When is farming unethical?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39038/when-is-farming-unethical) a culmination of several months of research on stackexchange and reddit. The reason I'm asking on gaming se is to win arguments in the chess or 9LX communities.

Comment: Now that you know (gasai) that I'm not new to the concept of elo, perhaps you don't mind giving me higher level answers? I mean I'm guessing you weren't answering directly because you thought I was new and so you were like baby-ing me or something? Or do I have to make another post for this? or what? I don't think this needs to be another post. I'm just asking plain and simple if *de facto* not *de jure* when you **reach rank X it is the case that you have beaten or drawn with at least 1 rank X-1**. in contrast in online chess or 9LX,you can reach 2000 without ever beating or drawing at 1700+.

Comment: I think the question breaks there. Its impossible in gaming to have not beaten an rank X-1 because 1- its not 1v1, there is always a range of players that you are matched with and 2- Usually, in those games if you are not using the random matchmaking (using custom lobbies) you dont win/lose LP. So it is statistically impossible to put a stick in the sand and say you never played against someone on either side of this stick. If you start from the bottom and go to the top you will have played against people of pretty much every ELO possible.

Comment: I dont know much about the World of chess but you seem to have a plan in mind where that could work, but in regular matchmaking games I don't think its feasible to stack the deck in the same way.

Comment: thank you very much Fredy31♦! so honoured an actual mod bothers to entertain my dumb questions

Comment: If it's "within 2 major ranks" then Gold player will be only able to play Silver/Gold/Platinum, not Diamonds.